# Sending image from java client to python server

Tags: java, python, http, networking

I'm new to java and I've been stuck on this problem for the last few days. I'm sending an image from a java client to a python server. I'm getting a 200 request, meaning the connection is being made. But the image is not being read on the server side. I've included the code - any help would be great.

Server Code

```
def index(request):


data = {"POST REQUEST, INSIDE INDEX, NO URL OR IMAGE SENT": False}
if request.method == "GET":
    return HttpResponse("GET REQUEST WORKS. RR.")

if request.method == "POST":
    # check to see if an image was uploaded
    if request.FILES.get("image", None) is not None:
        # grab the uploaded image 
        image = request.FILES["image"]

    # otherwise, assume that a URL was passed in
    else:
        # grab the URL from the request
        url = request.POST.get("url", None)

        # if the URL is None, then return an error
        if url is None:
            return HttpResponse("no URL is specified")

        # load the image and convert
        image = _grab_image(url=url)

    req = image
    arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(arr,-1) # 'load it as it is'

    Server = True   

    Student_Answers = []
    image = doc_Scan(img)
    if (image == "ERROR"):
        return HttpResponse("TAKE ANOTHER PICTURE")
    else:   
        images = crop_answer2(image)
        for i in range(0,8):
            ans = images[i]
            Answer = Input_Image(ans,Server)
            print ('Final Answer = ', Answer)
            Student_Answers.append(Answer)
        Results, score =  mark_paper(Server,Student_Answers)

    Worded_Respose = "The Student got ", score, " correct"

    return HttpResponse(Results, content_type="application/json")
else:
    return HttpResponse("NO POST REQUEST")
```

Client Code

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{

 String url = "http://########";
// 2. create obj for the URL class
 URL obj = new URL(url);
  // 3. open connection on the url
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
     con.setRequestMethod("POST");
     con.setDoOutput(true);


  try {

 System.out.println("Reading image from disk. ");
 img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

 ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
 baos.flush();

 byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
 baos.close();

 System.out.println("Sending image to server. ");

 OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
 DataOutputStream image = new DataOutputStream(out);

 image.writeInt(bytes.length);
 image.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

 System.out.println("Image sent to server. ");

 image.close();
 // close the output stream
 out.close();

  }catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     soc.close();
   }

   // define object for the reply from the server
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new        InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        //Get response from server
       int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
      // read in the response from the server
            String inputLine;
          StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
                 System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
      // close the input stream
                in.close();

     }

 }
```

Comment: I tripped at *“I'm getting a 200 request, meaning the connection is being made.”*. No clue what this could mean.

Comment: @spectras: terminology is indeed terrible, OP actually meant he got a HTTP response status code of 200, which means that the HTTP request is successfully retrieved and processed. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2

Comment: I mean a connection with the server is being made, and I'm getting a 200 returned to the client.

Comment: Okay, so the connection has come and (maybe) gone, the request was processed and a reply was sent back with a 200 status code. Alright, that's clearer. What's the content of the reply? All of the replies you generate have status 200, it would help knowing which was actually sent.

Comment: (by the way, you should change `HttpResponse` to the appropriate [subclasses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses) so a proper status code is sent when there is an error)

Comment: We send a jpeg from the client. There are some algorithms which do computation on the JPEG, the server should then send back a JSON to the client. I'm able to make it into the  "if request.method == "POST" loop; the server is realising that this is a POST request, but we get back nothing more.

Comment: You should have either an answer (with one of the error messages) or a tracelog on your server's error output (be it a console or a logfile). I bet it is *"no URL is specified"*, but it'd be better to be sure.